# Revolving point of polygon around circumference of ellipse

Tags: java, geometry, mouseevent, graphics2d

I have a design mad of 2 **ellipse'** and a **polygon triangle** as show in the image:

[image]

When I drag the "**arm**," point moves along with it as it should. The problem I'm having when I move the arm is that when the triangle's 3rd point is gets close to the same Y-axis as **P1** and **P2**, the triangle gets skinnier, due to the fact that P1 and P2 aren't moving.

**getPivot()** stores the center coordinate of the big ellipse. What I'm trying to achieve is based on where **P3** is whether more or less positive on the x-Axis from getPivot(), P1 and P2 should revolve around accordingly around the center to maintain the triangle's proportions.

So in theory if I were to move the arm to the right, p1 should revolve downward and P2 should revolve upward proportionately, but I can't seem to get the P1 to move.

The main thing I'm trying to get is for P1 and P2 to revolve around getPivot() (Point).
Below is what I've written to try to revolve P1 when the arm is dragged:

```
    _angle = _degree * (Math.PI / 180);

    double cosTheta = Math.cos(_angle);
    double sinTheta = Math.sin(_angle);

    int rX1 = (int) ( cosTheta * (_xPoints[0] - getPivot().x) - 
            sinTheta * (_yPoints[0] - getPivot().y) + getPivot().x);
    int rY1 = (int) ( sinTheta * (_xPoints[0] - getPivot().x) + 
            cosTheta * (_yPoints[0] - getPivot().y) + getPivot().y);

    _xPoints[0] = rX1;
    _yPoints[0] = rY1;
    _degree++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's arm center point is A, C=getPivot(), and R = radius of the big circle

vector AC = C-A = (C.X-A.X, C.Y-A.Y)

perpendicular vector CP = (-AC.Y, AC.X)

normalized (unit) vector cp = CP / |CP| (divide vector by it's length)

CP1 = cp*R, CP2 = -cp*R

P1 = C+cp*R, P2 = C-cp*R